# How to get the generic arguments of a TypeReference?

Tags: .net, reflection, mono.cecil

```
val it : TypeReference =
  System.Func`2<System.Object,TResult>
    {ContainsGenericParameter = true;
     DeclaringType = null;
     ElementType = System.Func`2;
     FullName = "System.Func`2<System.Object,TResult>";
     GenericArguments = seq [System.Object; TResult];
     GenericParameters = seq [];
     HasGenericArguments = true;
     HasGenericParameters = false;
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the `GenericArguments` of the above `Mono.Cecil` type and am not making any progress. Using the standard reflection API, I would just call `GetGenericArguments` method on the `Type`, but here there is nothing like that. The exists `GenericParameters` property, but that only works on top level `TypeDefinitions` whose parameters have not been been mapped to arguments. Using it on the type above would return an empty collection.

Could this be done somehow?

By the way, here is the F# script I am using to fetch the above mentioned type. My question is not at all specific for that particular type, I just needed one with generic arguments in a method parameter to illustrate my point.

```
#load "load-references-release.fsx"

open Mono.Cecil
open Mono.Cecil.Rocks

let mscorlib_path = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
let mscorlib = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(mscorlib_path).MainModule

let task = mscorlib.Types |> Seq.find (fun x -> x.Name = "Task`1")

let task_cons = task.GetConstructors()

let con =
    task_cons
    |> Seq.toArray
    |> fun x -> x.[8]

con.Parameters.[0].ParameterType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type specialization in Mono.Cecil is achieved through subclassing.

```
TypeReference type = ...;
if (type.IsGenericInstance) {
    GenericInstanceType instance = (GenericInstanceType) type;
    IList<TypeReference> genericArguments = instance.GenericArguments;
}
```